# How to read JSON file in emacs and display it in the scratch buffers?

Tags: json, scratch-buffer

I've a json data returned by endpoint which is as below:

```
{
"id":"1383",
"entryPoint":"Stranger in the night.",
"Source":"music"
}
```

What I need is to get the value associated with the key "entryPoint" displayed along with the default text, to produce something like that:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; Stranger in the night.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.
```

Maybe it is a silly question, but I'm just staring my adventure with emacs. Every little helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something similar to show a random `fortune` as my scratch message, so I've adapted my code for that (which is also why the commenting part might seem like overkill -- and indeed is if your data will only ever contain single-line values).

```el
(require 'json)
(require 'subr-x)

(defun my-json-scratch-message (jsonfile)
  "Combine `initial-scratch-message' with text from JSONFILE."
  (when-let* ((data (and (file-exists-p jsonfile)
                         (json-read-file jsonfile)))
              (string (alist-get 'entryPoint data)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert initial-scratch-message)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (forward-line 1)
      (narrow-to-region (point) (point))
      (insert string)
      (insert "\n")
      (let ((comment-start ";;")
            (comment-empty-lines t))
        (comment-region (point-min) (point-max)))
      (delete-trailing-whitespace (point-min) (point-max))
      (widen)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))

;; Set `initial-scratch-message' from `my-json-scratch-message'.
(when-let ((message (my-json-scratch-message "~/scratch.json")))
  (setq initial-scratch-message message))
```

---

> but what if I have a service at the specific url, and I want to obtain json from there?

```el
(require 'json)
(require 'subr-x)
(require 'url)
(defvar url-http-end-of-headers)
(defvar url-http-response-status)

(defun my-json-scratch-message (url key)
  "Combine `initial-scratch-message' with text for KEY of json from URL."
  (when-let* ((buf (url-retrieve-synchronously url :silent))
              (data (unwind-protect
                        (with-current-buffer buf
                          (and (>= url-http-response-status 200)
                               (< url-http-response-status 300)
                               (goto-char (1+ url-http-end-of-headers))
                               (json-parse-buffer :object-type 'alist)))
                      (kill-buffer buf)))
              (string (alist-get key data)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert initial-scratch-message)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (forward-line 1)
      (narrow-to-region (point) (point))
      (insert string)
      (insert "\n")
      (let ((comment-start ";;")
            (comment-empty-lines t))
        (comment-region (point-min) (point-max)))
      (delete-trailing-whitespace (point-min) (point-max))
      (widen)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))

;; Set `initial-scratch-message' from `my-json-scratch-message'.
(when-let ((message (my-json-scratch-message
                     "https://jsonendpoint.com/hello/endpoint/"
                     'message)))
  (setq initial-scratch-message message))

;; curl https://jsonendpoint.com/hello/endpoint/
;; {"message":"hello"}
```

Comment: And where did you put that code? In `init.el/.emacs` file?

Comment: Yes, in your init file (whichever of the possible init filenames you're actually using).

Comment: phils, but what if I have a service at the specific url, and I want to obtain json from there?

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(let* ((s "
   {
\"id\":\"1383\",
\"entryPoint\":\"Stranger in the night.\",
\"Source\":\"music\"
}")
       (json.el (with-temp-buffer
          (save-excursion (insert s))
          (json-read))))
  (format "%s %s"
      (alist-get 'entryPoint
             json.el)
      (alist-get 'Source
             json.el)))
```

When you `C-x C-e` the above snippet you get

```
"Stranger in the night. music"
```

You can set your `initial-scratch-message` to the above string.

---

I don't work with `javascript` or `json` much.  But often times I have to examine `json` data fetched with `curl` or `wget`.  So, I have the following in my `.emacs`.  The snippet pretty prints any `.json` file that you may open; works well for "not so large" `.json` files.

```lisp
(define-derived-mode json-mode javascript-mode "json-mode")

(setq auto-mode-alist
      `(
    ,@`(
        ("\\.json\\'" . json-mode))
    ,@auto-mode-alist))

(add-hook 'json-mode-hook #'json-pretty-print-buffer)
```